# If $r^3$ irrational then $r^n$ irrational for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I think that if $r^3$ irrational then $r^n$ irrational for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.

> $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, r^3 \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies r \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Your new (just edited) title doesn't make sense. It used to be $n \in \mathbb{N}$, now it's $n \in \mathbb{R}$. Please make up your mind. If $n \in \mathbb{R}$ then there will exist an $n$ such as $r^n$ is irrational for *any* $r \neq 0$.

Comment: It wasn't my edit originally, I'll clarify now. Honestly this question was pretty thoroughly vandalized.

Comment: By the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1900851/revisions), the change from $\in \mathbb{N}$ to $\in \mathbb{R}$ appears to have been yours. Regardless, I suggest you restore it to a meaningful state (definitely not $n \in \mathbb{R}$). As general advice, don't edit the question in a way that changes it completely (and invalidates posted answers). If the change is major enough for it to become a completely different question, then post it as a new question.

Comment: I was correcting the edits made by shakespeare. I had not noticed and it caused some confusion.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "*correct*". The way it is now (after you edited it) with $n \in \mathbb{R}$ it is an entirely different question than what you originally asked. And the answer is obviously negative, for example $n = 0$ and $n = \log_{r} 2$ both give a rational $r^n$ for $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

No. Consider

$$(2^\frac19)^3=2^\frac13$$

But
$$(2^\frac19)^9=2$$

Comment: Those are both rational. What are you implying? We are trying to prove or disprove irrationality.

Comment: The thing is clear: For $r=2^\frac19$, $r^3=2^\frac13$ is irrational. However $r^9=2$ is RATIONAL. So the statement is not true for any odd $n$.

Comment: He is disproving your thought in your original post which is different from that of the title. He gives $r$ such that $r^3$ is irrational yet $r^9$ is rational.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if $r=a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $r^3=a^3/b^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$ so the implication in the title holds (proof by contrapositive). However as hkmather pointed out, this is not true for other $n$.

Comment: I'm confused because of the edit. The question specifically referred to the original composition. Proving that r^1 is irrational.

Comment: @SunshineTS your question asks "assuming A, prove B" where A="$r^3$ irrational" and B="$r$ irrational". I have proved "assuming not B, then not A" which actually is the same thing. This equivalent statement is called the contrapositive.

Comment: Which seems to be different from what hkmather802 is implying.

Comment: @SunshineTS it is not; he is talking about general $n$, I am talking only about $n=1$. What you said is not true for general $n$, but it is true for $n=1$

Comment: Sweet. I thought so. Thanks.